# TensorFlow : Enqueuing and dequeuing a queue from multiple threads

Tags: tensorflow, python-multithreading

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows :
I have a list `trainimgs` of filenames. I have defined a

- `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` with its `capacity=len(trainimgs)` and `min_after_dequeue=0`.
- This `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` is expected to be filled by `trainimgs` for a specified `epochlimit` number of times.
- A number of threads are expected to work in parallel. Each thread dequeues an element from the `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` and does some operations on it and enqueues it to another queue. I have got that part right.
- However once `1 epoch` of `trainimgs` have been processed and the `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` is empty, provided that the current epoch `e < epochlimit`, the queue must again be filled up and the threads must work again.

The good news is : I have got it working in a certain case (See **PS** at the end !!)

The bad news is : I think that there is a better way of doing this.

The method I am using to do this now is as follows (I have simplified the functions and have removed e image processing based preprocessing and subsequent enqueuing  but the heart of the processing remains the same !!) :

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_filename_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=len(trainimgs), min_after_dequeue=0, dtypes=tf.string, seed=0)
    queue_size = train_filename_queue.size()
    trainimgtensor = tf.constant(trainimgs)
    close_queue = train_filename_queue.close()
    epoch = tf.Variable(initial_value=1, trainable=False, dtype=tf.int32)
    incrementepoch = tf.assign(epoch, epoch + 1, use_locking=True)
    supplyimages = train_filename_queue.enqueue_many(trainimgtensor)
    value = train_filename_queue.dequeue()

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord)
    sess.run(supplyimages)
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=work, args=(coord, value, sess, epoch, incrementepoch, supplyimages, queue_size, lock, close_queue)) for  i in range(200)] 
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    coord.join(threads)
```

The work function is as follows :

```
def work(coord, val, sess, epoch, incrementepoch, supplyimg, q, lock,\
         close_op):
while not coord.should_stop():
    if sess.run(q) > 0:
        filename, currepoch = sess.run([val, epoch])
        filename = filename.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
        print(filename + ' ' + str(currepoch))
    elif sess.run(epoch) < 2:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            if sess.run(q) == 0:
                print("The previous epoch = %d"%(sess.run(epoch)))
                sess.run([incrementepoch, supplyimg])
                sz = sess.run(q)
                print("The new epoch = %d"%(sess.run(epoch)))
                print("The new queue size = %d"%(sz))
        finally:
            lock.release()
    else:
        try:
            sess.run(close_op)
        except tf.errors.CancelledError:
            print('Queue already closed.')
        coord.request_stop()
return None
```

So, although this works, I have a feeling that there is a better and cleaner way to achieve this. So, in a nutshell my questions are :

1. Is there a simpler and cleaner way of achieving this task in TensorFlow ?
2. Is there any problem with this code's logic ? I am not very experienced with multithreading scenarios, so any obvious faults which have skipped my attention would be very helpful to me.

P.S : It seems that this code is not Perfect after all. When I ran with 1.2 million images and 200 threads, it ran. However when I run it for 10 images and 20 threads, it gives the following error :

```
CancelledError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_0_random_shuffle_queue' is closed.
     [[Node: random_shuffle_queue_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](random_shuffle_queue, Const)]]
```

I thought I got that covered by `except tf.errors.CancelledError`. What the hell is going on here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out the answer. The problem was that multiple threads were clashing together on various points in the `work()` function.
The following `work()` function works perfectly.

```
def work(coord, val, sess, epoch, maxepochs, incrementepoch, supplyimg, q, lock, close_op):
    print('I am thread number %s'%(threading.current_thread().name))
    print('I can see a queue with size %d'%(sess.run(q)))
    while not coord.should_stop():
        lock.acquire()
        if sess.run(q) > 0:
            filename, currepoch = sess.run([val, epoch])
            filename = filename.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
            tid = threading.current_thread().name
            print(filename + ' ' + str(currepoch) + ' thread ' + str(tid))
        elif sess.run(epoch) < maxepochs:
            print('Thread %s has acquired the lock'%(threading.current_thread().name))
            print("The previous epoch = %d"%(sess.run(epoch)))
            sess.run([incrementepoch, supplyimg])
            sz = sess.run(q)
            print("The new epoch = %d"%(sess.run(epoch)))
            print("The new queue size = %d"%(sz))
    else:
            coord.request_stop()
        lock.release()

    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a single thread calling enqueue_many epochs times enqueue the correct number of images. It can then close the queue. This would let you simplify your work function and other threads.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to use multiple threads for speedup since there are complex preprocessing steps i have to do

Comment: You can use one thread to just enqueue file names in the main queue, and then multiple threads to dequeue those file names, preprocess, and enqueue them in the final queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the GIL will prevent any actual parallelism from being done in those threads.

To get performance with tensorflow you need to keep your data in tensorflow.

Tensor Flow's [reading data guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) explains how to address a very similar sort of problem.

More specifically, you seem to have rewritten a significant chunk of `string_input_producer`.

Comment: I am using actual data. `string_input_producer()` does not tell that which epoch of data it is extracting at any moment. It just makes sue that any piece of data is extracted `epoch` number of times. So, my implementation is not a rewriting of `string_input_producer()`.  I do understand that the way I am doing it is perhaps not the best way, but I need to keep a direct and very precise check on the particular epoch and iteration a data comes from and I did not seem to find anything in the data guide about it. I will read it again though.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I guess I don't completely understand the problem. Why not use (string, epoch) pairs?

Comment: I have used it. I have used the `epoch` variable to compute the `epoch`